# Set Binding property in Style in XAML C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-style

I'm searching for a way to set the binding property `UpdateSourceTrigger` in a `Style`. Currently I'm setting it on every `TextBox` manually like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding boundValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

What I want to do is something like this (But this obviously doesn't work):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger" Value="PropertyChanged" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding boundValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles are meant for [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style(v=vs.110).aspx)s (and derivated controls).

[Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a FrameworkElement.

Anyway you can create your own [markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml) for setting Binding's properties that your need:

```
public class PropertyChangedBinding : Binding
{
    public PropertyChangedBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }

    public PropertyChangedBinding()
        : base()
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

So in your XAML you can use `{local:PropertyChangedBinding ...}`.

Comment: That works very good. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @RomanoZumbé